# How to find the total number of links in webpage using selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already tried in Java

```
int elementsCount = allElements.size();
```

.size() are used in Java

Is there any options in Python, Rather than using FORLOOP.

Comment: can you show the `find_elements` command you use?

Comment: `total = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("a")

print(len(total))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `len()` in Python

```
allElements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
elementsCount = len(allElements)
print(elementsCount)
```

Comment: I tried this command `total = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("a")

print(len(total))`

Comment: To get all the links you should use **find_elements_by_tag_name** so your code will be `total = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")` else it will return only one element( the first one). Then you can do `print(len(total))`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `find_elements_by_tag_name` this gives you a list of all the elements with `a` tag.

if you use `find_element_by_tag_name` you just get the first one.

Like this:

```
total = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a") 
print(len(total))
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

We can use .size() method easily.

```
public void testone() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\JARS\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://amazon.in");

public void apptest3() {
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")).sendKeys("mobile");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit']")).click();
        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

        System.out.println(links.size());
```

**System.out.println(links.size());**